# call from module vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, encryption, module

hello guys need help i have code md5 to do crypt and decrypt now this code i put it in module and need call from form how i can do that (vb.net)

```
    Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Text

Module Crypt
    Public Function Encrypt(ByVal toEncrypt As String, ByVal key As String, ByVal useHashing As Boolean) As String
        Dim keyArray As Byte()
        Dim toEncryptArray As Byte() = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toEncrypt)

        If useHashing = True Then
            Dim hashmd5 As New MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
            keyArray = hashmd5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key))
        Else
            keyArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key)
        End If

        Dim tdes As New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider()
        tdes.Key = keyArray
        tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB
        tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7

        Dim cTransform As ICryptoTransform = tdes.CreateEncryptor()
        Dim resultArray As Byte() = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length)

        Return (Convert.ToBase64String(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length))
    End Function
    Public Function Decrypt(ByVal toDecrypt As String, ByVal key As String, ByVal useHashing As Boolean) As String
        Dim keyArray As Byte()
        Dim toEncryptArray As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(toDecrypt)

        If useHashing = True Then
            Dim hashmd5 As New MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
            keyArray = hashmd5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key))
        Else
            keyArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key)
        End If

        Dim tdes As New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider()
        tdes.Key = keyArray
        tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB
        tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7

        Dim cTransform As ICryptoTransform = tdes.CreateDecryptor()
        Dim resultArray As Byte() = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length)

        Return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultArray)
    End Function
End Module
```

Comment: Looks like you already have a module right there so you can just call `Encrypt` and `Decrypt` from anywhere

Comment: i know i have module but i need know how i can call when i call encrypt i get error " Argument not specified for parameter 'key' of 'Public Function Encrypt(toEncrypt As String, key As String, useHashing As Boolean) As String'  " .
"

Answer (score -2):

Module = static class

static = Shared in vb.net

```
NotInheritable Class SecurityModule

    Private Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Shared Function Encrypt(parameters) As String
      // Your implementation
    End Function

  Public Shared Function Decrypt(parameters) As String
      // Your implementation
  End Function

End Class
```

NotInheritable is like sealed. Shared is like method of static class.

To call

```
SecurityModule.Encrypt(...)
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: sorry sami but i don't understand this answer i put my code in module and i make form1 and need call function encrypt from button

Comment: i add my code to class and make this u explain but can't make call when i write SecurityModule.   i get equals and ReferenceEquals i not get Encrypt

Comment: I got help from some online sources and my vb.net exp. anyway happy that your issue fixed.